# Retrieve system Up Time via VBA (Access/Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Is there anyway that in Access VBA (or Excel for that manner) that I can see the current system Up Time?

I know that in task manager I can see it, so can I via VBA retrieve, that kind of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **GetTickCount**
>
> The GetTickCount function retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started. It is limited to the resolution of the system timer. To obtain the system timer resolution, use the GetSystemTimeAdjustment function.
>
> ```
> DWORD GetTickCount(VOID);
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> This function has no parameters.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days.
>
> Library: Use Kernel32.lib.

API calls need to be Declared, see `Declare` in help. From the Library name we know the dll name is kernel32.dll.

```
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTickCount" () As Long
```

To use

```
msgbox GetTickCount()
```

Be aware this is unsigned. VBA treats all longs as signed so larger numbers will print as negative numbers, just don't do sums on them..

Another way is to use WMI.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.lastbootuptime & " " & objItem.caption
Next
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  `GetTickCount` is definitely going to perform better than WMI.

Comment: Might be an idea to include the 64-bit declaration as well, i.e. `#If VBA7 Then`
`Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTickCount" () As Long`
`#Else`
`Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTickCount" () As Long`
`#End If`.  (I don't usually include the `Alias` bit but, based on what is in your answer, I hope I have correctly added it in to that code.)

Comment: My declaration came from VB6's API Viewer. I copied and pasted it.