Get System Up Time in VBA excel
I need to obtain the system uptime in excel vba, this is available on the Task Manager as such:

I found the below online from 7 years ago:
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub test()
Debug.Print GetTickCount()
End Sub

this outputs : 206329937
if i devide this by 8400 i get 15 days when it should be 2 days 9 hours etc.
Not sure whats going wrong.
Also read online that I should use an IF formula to declare if its 64 bit or 32 bit but im also not sure how to do this?
Any advice would be great thank you.
UPDATE:
Turns out the first 6 numbers : 206329 will convert to the right time. I have no idea what the remaining numbers mean does anyone know?
Dim NewTime
NewTime = (Left(GetTickCount(), 6)) / 86400

Debug.Print NewTime

I tried to convert the time to dd:hh:mm:ss format and it only works when its formatted on the worksheet as a custom cell format.
Very weird no idea again why this is the case but this is the result i get when using :
Debug.Print Format(NewTime, "DD:MM:HH:SS")

01:01:09:27
very confusing !

Have you tried using WMI? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40980046/478884

I read on that article that it wasn't recommended to use that option?
Ive just realised the first 6 numbers will convert to the right time, so im thinking of just using the first 6 numbers to get the calculation. Not sure what the remaining numbers mean though?

https://www.devhut.net/vba-computer-uptime/  has a function which gives output matching Task Manager's value.

Fractional seconds and timezone offset?

Your main error is that you divide by 8400.
The ticks are measured in ms (milliseconds). So to get the number of days, you need to divide by 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).
That would give 2.388 days in your case.
To get the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds, you just need some math. The logic is to calculate the full number of days, subtract the number of ticks used by that from the original number of ticks. Now do the same for hours (but divide only by (60 * 60 * 1000) and so on.
The following code does that with the help of a small function - note that the first parameter (ticks) is passed ByRef and modified in that function. Also note that I used 24& to force VBA to use a long value, else 24 * 60 * 60 will throw an overflow error.
Sub test()
    Dim ticks  As Long
    ticks = GetTickCount()
    ' Just to test OP value:
    ticks = 206329937

    Dim days As Long, hours As Long, minutes As Long, seconds As Long
    days = getTimepart(ticks, 24& * 60 * 60)
    hours = getTimepart(ticks, 60 * 60)
    minutes = getTimepart(ticks, 60)
    seconds = getTimepart(ticks, 1)
    Debug.Print days, hours, minutes, seconds
End Sub

Function getTimepart(ByRef ticks As Long, divisor As Long) As Long
    divisor = divisor * 1000
    getTimepart = Int(ticks / divisor)
    ticks = ticks - (getTimepart * divisor)
End Function

In your case, this prints
 2             9             18            49 


Amazing thanks so much, all makes sense now I know its in Milliseconds explains why my calculations were not calculating. Super ! Thanks for the additional code too very helpful :) !

Nice, voted it up!

From https://www.devhut.net/vba-computer-uptime/ :
Sub test()
    Debug.Print GetPCUptime()
End Sub

Function GetPCUptime() As String
    Dim oOSs As Object, oOS As Object
    Set oOSs = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery( _
                 "SELECT SystemUpTime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System")
    For Each oOS In oOSs
        GetPCUptime = SecsToDHMS(oOS.SystemUpTime)
        Exit For 'only need the one...
    Next
End Function

'Format period in seconds to DD:HH:MM:SS
Function SecsToDHMS(ByVal v As Long) As String
    Dim arr, el, s As String
    arr = Array(86400, 3600, 60, 1)
    For Each el In arr
        s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ":", "") & Format(v \ el, "00")
        v = v Mod el        
    Next el
    SecsToDHMS = s
End Function


THanks for this, it gives me 2.42 days but not the format i was hoping for ! Ideally wanting it in DD:HH:MM:SS format would you mind adjusting this to output like this please?
thank you

Added some updates above

Nice, voted it up!
